# DotLiquid Template Engine Example Output Problem

Tags: c#, template-engine, dotliquid

I am trying to use the example from http://dotliquidmarkup.org/try-online.
I have the following code using the NuGet package DotLiquid

namespace TestDotLiquidLoop
{

```
public class User : Drop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        //const string template1 = "{{ user.name | upcase }} has to do:{% for item in user.tasks -%}{ { item.name } }{% endfor -%}";
        const string template = "<p>{{ user.name | upcase }} has to do:</p>" +
            "< ul >{% for item in user.tasks -%}" +
            "< li >{ { item.name } }</ li >" +
            "{% endfor -%}" +
            "</ ul > ";
        Template preparedTemplate = Template.Parse(template);


        var user = new User
        {
            Name = "Tim Jones",
            Tasks = new List<Task>
        {
            new Task { Name = "Documentation" },
            new Task { Name = "Code comments" }
        }
        };
        Console.WriteLine(preparedTemplate.Render(DotLiquid.Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new { tempuser = user })));

    }
}
```

}

I am not getting the output correctly. My output is like this.I know its something silly but can anyone help me out with this ?

```
<p> has to do:</p>< ul ></ ul >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably missed `new { tempuser = user }` that you renamed anonymous object property to `tempuser` at some point. This `new { user }` is equivalent to this `new { user = user }`. To reference `tempuser` inside template you need to just change name.

```
        string template = "<p>{{ tempuser.name | upcase }} has to do:</p>" +
                                "< ul >{% for item in tempuser.tasks -%}" +
                                "< li >{{ item.name }}</ li >" +
                                "{% endfor -%}" +
                                "</ ul > ";
        Template preparedTemplate = Template.Parse(template);

        var user = new User
        {
            Name = "Tim Jones",
            Tasks = new List<Task>
            {
                new Task { Name = "Documentation" },
                new Task { Name = "Code comments" }
            }
        };
        Template.RegisterSafeType(typeof(Task), new []{"Name"});
        Console.WriteLine(preparedTemplate.Render(DotLiquid.Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new { tempuser = user })));
```

Comment: if I change the template as you suggested then I am getting error like below

<p>Liquid error: Object of type 'User' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'. has to do:</p>< ul ></ ul >

Comment: I've added entire Main method. Also you have problem with registering `Task` type to print task name correctly.

Comment: I think you replaced `{{ user.name | upcase }}`  with `{{ tempuser | upcase }}` that gives you error, change it to `{{ tempuser.name | upcase }}`

Comment: No, I did not change that way.its the same as you explained but still the same error
const string template = "<p>{{ tempuser .name | upcase }} has to do:</p>" +
                "< ul >{% for item in tempuser .tasks -%}" +
                "< li >{ { item.name } }</ li >" +
                "{% endfor -%}" +
                "</ ul > ";
This is my current template as you suggested

Comment: you have space `tempuser .tasks` and `tempuser .name | upcase` before dot

Comment: Sorry, Yes removed the space got the output correct.
Thanks a lot for your time.So, I mark is solved